# Pass props to datas vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, vue-props

I know this questions often appears in Stackoverflow, but even with the mutiple answers, I can't manage to solve my answer.

I'am usin an axios get call in my parent component and send the datas via props to a child component. I want to pass props to datas to re-use them to build a chart vie apexChart. And the instance doesn't recognize the datas.

```
<template>
  <div id="gauge">

    <apexchart type="radialBar" height="800" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apexchart>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    radialChartDatas: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      allDatas: this.radialChartDatas,
      series: [30],
      topicQuote: null,
      chartOptions: {

        //some code for the char//

        labels: []
      }
    };
  },

  created() {
    let newlabel = this.chartOptions.labels;
    newlabel.push(this.allDatas[0].survey_topicTitle);
  },

  watch: {
    radialChartDatas(val) {
      this.allDatas = val;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

It appears that allDatas is undefined. 
Any idea?

ps : my axios call in the parent component is in a created function.

Thank you!!

Comment: What is the parent component here? What is the child component here? What data you are referring to? What props are you referring to? How are you passing the props from the parent to child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the `Reactivity` system in Vue. Just change the following

```
this.radialChartDatas = response.data;
```

to

```
this.radialChartDatas.push(...response.data);
```

You can read about [Array Change Detection](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection)

Answer (score 0):

This is the parent component :

```
<template>
  <div style="margin-top:100px" class="home">
    <RadialChartPage v-bind:radialChartDatas="radialChartDatas" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import RadialChartPage from "@/components/RadialChartPage.vue";
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "RadialChart",

  components: {
    RadialChartPage
  },

  data() {
    return {
      radialChartDatas: []
    };
  },

  created() {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3005/submit/` + this.$route.params.id)
      .then(response => {
        this.radialChartDatas = response.data;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
};
</script>

</style>
```